If I'm not sure if I should make a bracha, should I make it?
For a sheheciyanu or birchas hatov hameitiv, if I'm not sure if I should make a bracha, should you or would it be a bracha levatalah?

ספק ברכות להקל https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Safek_Brachot_LeHakel

So even for birchas hanein, one would not make the bracha?

Pretty much. These laws are fairly involved and from a glance the link I shared covers the main bases (and remedies, courses of action one should take instead) I am aware of. Main exception is Birchat Hamazon

Although the general rule of thumb with brachos is that ספק ברכות להקל - never to make a brachah in case of doubt, so as not to inadvertently transgress brachah l'vatalah (Shulchan Aruch OC 209:3), some say that shehechiyanu is an exception to that rule.
The Bach (OC 29) writes:

וליתא כדפי' דבספק נמי אסור לברך משום ספק ברכה לבטלה פן יהא עובר על לא
תשא את שם ה' אלהיך לשוא אבל לפע"ד דאיכא לחלק בין ברכת שהחיינו לשאר
ברכות דברכת שהחיינו שבאה על שמחת לבו של אדם יכול לברך אע"פ שאינו ודאי
דחייב לברך דאינו עובר על לא תשא אם הוא שמח ומברך לו יתעלה על שהחייהו
וקיימו עד הזמן הזה אבל כאן דמברך אשר קדשנו במצותיו וצונו וכו' פשיטא
דכיון דאיכא ספק אינו יכול לברך ולומר וצונו דהויא ספק ברכה לבטלה דאסור
לד"ה

The Bach posits that since shehechiyanu essentially is a berachah on simchas libo - the feeling of intense happiness - it would not be considered a berachah levatalah even if one is not obligated. Although other berachos are said on a specific occurrence/action (and in absence of that occurrence/action is levatalah), this beracha is said for an emotion.
An earlier source for this idea is in Teshuvas Rivash (505). [For further discussion of this idea, see also: Tzlach (Berachos 60a), Pri Chadash (432), Teshuvas Chasam Sofer (OC 55), and Teshuvas Tzitz Eliezer (Vol 13, Siman 20:5)]
I wrote the above because the tag was 'halacha theory'. Practically, some poskim disagree with the Bach's disctinction. For example, Mishne Berura (233:12) invokes the principle of safek berachos lehakel even by Shecheyanu. For practical ruling, as always, AYLOR!

It's important to note that on the flip side, the obligation to make the brachah is significantly lesser by shehechiyanu, because the entire blessing is classified by amny rishonim - and codified in Shulchan Aruch - as reshus.
